# Do master's degree grades affect graduate school applications?

Tags: phd

Recently I got my master's degree from a relatively unknown university, (500-600 ranking). Due to psychological implications, (signs of severe clinical depression) of COVID quaranteens and other factors I did not manage to get very good grades, 9.11 out of 10.

Due to a number of factors I want to apply for graduate school at the US. Will my master's degree grades be taken into consideration along with my undergraduate ones? These produce a total grade of 9.3 out of 10.

I mention my grades because many of the professors I whould like to work with are employed at Harvard, Yale, University of Chicago, and in general, high-ranking universities. Is there any chance for me to get into such institutions with such grades?

Thank you!

Comment: We can't really answer individual questions about whether an applicant has a chance for a specific program at a specific school. Instead, we have a canonical Q&A covering how these decisions are typically made in the US. The only way to find out about your personal case is to apply; the advice for everyone is to apply broadly, that is, not to apply only to the most selective schools (yet also not to avoid them entirely if that's your interest), even if you have a very strong application. Admissions decisions are quite stochastic.

Comment: Unless we are misinterpreting the grading scale, having grades corresponding to >90% of the grade scale does not actually sound like bad grades, it is the other way.